# Google Structured Data: Are delivery time and transit time mandatory for OfferShippingDetails

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I want to configure Google structured data for a product details page with its shipping price. But I see additional properties `deliveryTime` and `transitTime` in the [**Google** documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/product?hl=en#microdata_2). I am not sure if these properties are mandatory or optional to implement along with `shippingRate`. Secondly, how can we figure out on [Schema.org](https://schema.org/OfferShippingDetails), which property is mandatory and which is not?

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Nice trinket</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <div itemtype="https://schema.org/Product" itemscope>
      <meta itemprop="sku" content="trinket-12345" />
      <meta itemprop="gtin14" content="12345678901234" />
      <meta itemprop="name" content="Nice trinket" />
      <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/16x9/trinket.jpg" />
      <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/4x3/trinket.jpg" />
      <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/1x1/trinket.jpg" />
      <meta itemprop="description" content="Trinket with clean lines" />
      <div itemprop="brand" itemtype="https://schema.org/Brand" itemscope>
        <meta itemprop="name" content="MyBrand" />
      </div>
      <div itemprop="offers" itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer" itemscope>
        <link itemprop="url" href="https://www.example.com/trinket_offer" />
        <meta itemprop="itemCondition" content="https://schema.org/NewCondition" />
        <meta itemprop="availability" content="https://schema.org/InStock" />
        <meta itemprop="price" content="39.99" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
        <meta itemprop="priceValidUntil" content="2020-11-20" />
        <div itemprop="shippingDetails" itemtype="https://schema.org/OfferShippingDetails" itemscope>
          <div itemprop="shippingRate" itemtype="https://schema.org/MonetaryAmount" itemscope>
            <meta itemprop="value" content="3.49" />
            <meta itemprop="currency" content="USD" />
          </div>
          <div itemprop="shippingDestination" itemtype="https://schema.org/DefinedRegion" itemscope>
            <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="US" />
          </div>
          <div itemprop="deliveryTime" itemtype="https://schema.org/ShippingDeliveryTime" itemscope>
            <div itemprop="handlingTime" itemtype="https://schema.org/QuantitativeValue" itemscope>
              <meta itemprop="minValue" content="0" />
              <meta itemprop="maxValue" content="1" />
              <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="DAY" />
            </div>
            <div itemprop="transitTime" itemtype="https://schema.org/QuantitativeValue" itemscope>
              <meta itemprop="minValue" content="1" />
              <meta itemprop="maxValue" content="5" />
              <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="DAY" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div itemprop="review" itemtype="https://schema.org/Review" itemscope>
        <div itemprop="author" itemtype="https://schema.org/Person" itemscope>
          <meta itemprop="name" content="Fred Benson" />
        </div>
        <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemtype="https://schema.org/Rating" itemscope>
          <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
          <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemtype="https://schema.org/AggregateRating" itemscope>
        <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="89" />
        <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.4" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Regards,

Lodhi

Comment: Check the example in Product with an offer and shipping details https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/product?hl=en#product-with-shipping-example . This example has the properties you are asking about.

Comment: @ thanks for the comment. But I already have included the code from same section. It's just difference of language. The question is, are they recommend properties or required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What’s required by Google to consider structured data valid can be just a subset of what’s required for certain Google search features like rich snippets.

Google’s documentation categorises properties into ‘required’ and ‘recommended’ for each supported type. In your case, the Offer type’s properties are documented by Google here:

- https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/product?hl=en#offer-properties

The documentation says price or priceSpecification.price are required, and priceValidUntil among others are recommended.

You mention deliveryTime and transitTime. The above link slightly further down documents

> **ShippingDeliveryTime**
> This type is not used by product snippets.

so it is useful to include for purposes other than product snippets.

Schema.org is just the schema. It doesn’t say what properties are required for specific Google functionality.

Comment: It is used for Merchant listings.

"ShippingDeliveryTime is used to share the total delay between the receipt of an order and the goods reaching the final customer."